# Ruby on Rails: accessing form elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dom

I have a **form** with a **set** of links and hidden inputs like this:

```
<div><%=link_to '&darr;', {}, {:href =>'#',
     :onclick => "return moveDown(#{photo.id});"}%></div>
<%= photo_form.hidden_field :position %>
```

How do I change input value when link is clicked without hard-coding input ids on client side? i dont want to use selectors also. is there any KISS solution?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't want to use ids and selectors? How do you think js will know the element to work with? :)

Comment: yes, I don't want to hard-code auto generated ids on client side.
I want to pass them from server. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I'd suggest using non-obtrusive Javascript. I presume you're trying to sort the list of links and keep track of their position. jQuery has built-in support for sortable/draggable functionality like this.

Also, [this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists) shows how to create such sortable lists (although it uses Prototype JS framework).